# Search opens when icon is clicked but won't close when close icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have an error on my JavaScript using WordPress where I can open the search but can't close it. I have a functions.php where there is a `wp_enqueue_script` for a live-search script, Search.js, Index.js, header.php and footer.php with code necessary with the problem:

functions.php code:

```
wp_enqueue_script('live-search-javascript',
get_theme_file_uri('/js/modules/Search.js'), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
```

header.php icon code:

```
<span class="search-trigger js-search-trigger"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

footer.php code:

```
<div class="search-overlay">
  <div class="search-overlay__top"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
      <i class="fa fa-search search-overlay__icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <input type="text" class="search-term" placeholder="Search DC" id="search-term">
      <i class="fa fa-window-close search-overlay__close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Index.js code:

```
import "../css/style.scss";
import $ from 'jquery';

// Our modules / classes
import MobileMenu from "./modules/MobileMenu";
import HeroSlider from "./modules/HeroSlider";
import GoogleMap from "./modules/GoogleMap";
import Search from "./modules/Search";

// Instantiate a new object using our modules/classes
const mobileMenu = new MobileMenu();
const heroSlider = new HeroSlider();
const googleMap = new GoogleMap();
const mySearch = new Search();
```

Search.js code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class Search {
  constructor() {
    this.openButton = $(".js-search-trigger");
    this.closeButton = $(".search-overlay__close");
    this.searchOverlay = $(".search-overlay");
    this.events();

  }

  events() {
    this.openButton.on("click", this.openOverlay.bind(this));
    this.closeButton.on("click", this.closeOverlay.bind(this));
  }


  openOverlay() {
    this.searchOverlay.addClass("search-overlay--active");

  }

  closeOverlay() {
    this.searchOverlay.removeClass("search-overlay--active");
  }
}

export default Search;
```

The search opens, it just won't close. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you've got 99% modern JS there, but you're still  bringing in jQuery for the sole purpose of performing a `document.querySelector()`. This is just a personal opinion, and maybe you've got other uses for jQuery, but for this sample at least I think I'd kill it off completely.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in `closeOverlay` to see if it is firing?

Comment: I found out that it will close, only I have to scroll down to a point where it can. I want it to close from the very top of the page.

Comment: "Open" and "Close" are just visual things that you are controlling using CSS classes. If your JS events are firing, then you probably need to debug your CSS. If you JS events aren't firing, that's JS. So, are your events firing. Ignore "open" and "close", just write to the console log or alert

Comment: I think I found where i can edit the CSS file. It is in a file called search-overlay.scss.

Comment: You've posted JS but your problem, based on the comment and answer, appears to be related to CSS. I'm not certain how someone in the future reading the question and answer as posted helpful?

Comment: Apparently, it's behaving where it cant do any functions at the top of the page, so it needs to be moved down to a place where it can do searches. So I changed the ```.search-overlay``` only to right and remove 'left', 'top', and 'bottom.' Then resize the body.admin-bar & {
    top: 32px;
  } to ```top: 90px;```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it does close only I have to scroll down and not at the top of the page.
The file where it can be fixed is called `search-overlay.scss` in the css file. The search bar needs to have a place where it can be executed to do searches, not at the very top of the page where the header is.